# Why does value change when static_casting?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
double i = static_cast<double>(static_cast<int>((273.15)*100))/100;
std::cout<<(i==273.14); //1
return 0;
}
```

i equals to 273.14 and I can't understand why

Comment: `.15` cannot be accurately represented in binary.

Comment: I suspect a more concise question would be why `std::cout << static_cast<int>(273.15*100);` prints 27314, whereas  `std::cout << (273.15*100)` prints 27315. Hint: try `std::cout << std::setprecision(32) <<  (273.15*100)` , then think about what kind of truncation that static cast to `int` is doing.

Comment: @ChrisMM - It can be *accurately* represented.   It cannot be *precisely* represented as a `double`.    In other words, the value stored as a `double` will not be exactly equal to `.15`.   But the value stored will be the closest value to `0.15` that a `double` CAN exactly represent.   In this case (with the OP's implementation) that value is slightly less than `0.15`   (with the difference not detectable in less than 5 (possibly as many as 8) significant figures - which means the relative error is less than `1E-4`  i.e. 0.01%).

Answer (score 0):

Analogous example with bases 10 and 30: As 3 is a factor of 30, 1/3 can be represented exactly in base 30:

```
1/3 = 10/30 = 10*30-1
```

i. e. it is

```
0.A30
```

However 1/3 is periodic in decimal!

Now consider a more complex number:

```
0.3A30 = 3*30-1 + 10*30-2 = 0,‾1‾
```

where ‾1‾ is the period. Problem: we now need to round as we have only a limited number of digits available, let's say 4, so we have (this is where the error gets introduced):

```
0.1111 = 3/30 + 9/900 + 27/27000 + 81/810000 = 0.39TL30
```

Now multiplying by *100<sub>30</sub>*, i.e. *900<sub>10</sub>*, gives *39.TL<sub>30</sub>*. Converting this to a base-30 integer (which means truncating the decimals) gives *39<sub>30</sub>* and dividing by *100<sub>30</sub>* finally gives *0.39<sub>30</sub>* instead of the expected *0.3A<sub>30</sub>*.